# Data from file - bytes sent don't match fread()

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, fread

I have this method:

```
char*
Sender::PrepareData(char* filename, unsigned long long int bytesToTransfer)
{
    FILE* dataFile = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (dataFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    cout << "File Open: " << filename << endl;

    char* theData;
    theData = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bytesToTransfer);
    if (theData == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    size_t bytesRead = fread(theData, 1, bytesToTransfer, dataFile);
    if (bytesRead != bytesToTransfer || theData == NULL) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

    cout << "Data Read -- Num Bytes: " << bytesRead << endl;
    cout << "Data to Send: " << *theData << endl;

    return theData;
}
```

Which eventually calls this:

```
//char * buf here == theData above
Sender::SendMessage(struct sockaddr_in toNode, char * buf)
{
    #if logging > 1
        cout << "Sending: " << buf << endl;
    #endif
    
    int n;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    n = sendto(mySocket, buf, strlen(buf),0,
                (const struct sockaddr *)&toNode,length);

    if (n < strlen(buf)) 
        perror("Sendto");

    #if logging > 1
        cout << "Sent: " << n << " bytes of data\n";
    #endif
}
```

My `t.bin` file contains:

```
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
```

My test cases are somewhat odd though...

```
File Open: t.bin
Data Read -- Num Bytes: 999
Data to Send: #
Sending: ######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!
Sent: 999 bytes of data
```

---

```
File Open: t.bin
Data Read -- Num Bytes: 1000
Data to Send: #
Sending: ######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!![non-printable-character][non-printable-character] //<---
Sent: 1002 bytes of data
```

---

```
File Open: t.bin
Data Read -- Num Bytes: 1001
Data to Send: #
Sending: ######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
######################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
!!!!!!!
Sent: 1001 bytes of data
```

---

Notice how `999` and `1001` bytes to send are fine - but for some reason if I do `1000` it's adding an extra 2 bytes when sending! Likewise on the receiving end, I get:

> Received 999 bytes of data
>
> Received 1002 bytes of data
>
> Received 1001 bytes of data

What don't I understand here? Why does `1000` bytes blow up my test case?

Comment: strlen() in network code - again:(

Comment: @MartinJames It's all I've known! Blame Beej :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should null-terminate the string (`theData`) after `fread`. Alternatively, you can pass `bytesRead` to `SendMessage` and then use that value instead of `strlen(buf)`. This should give the desired result even if your data happens to include the null-terminator char (`'\0'`).

Comment: To actually answer your question: cases 999 and 1001 appear to work by chance, which is sort of misleading. You are not able to count on even them working in the future – it all depends on what happens to be in the memory right after the chunk pointed to by theData. So, for all practical purposes, your code here does not work for any length of data being sent.